# How do I run VLC with command-line parameters when clicking the icon?

Tags: bash, vlc

I've tried changing the Info.plist to point towards a bash script which runs the executable with the parameters that I want. This doesn't seem to work even though when I invoke it from Terminal.app with the same parameters the tests check out.

If it matters, this is 10.5 with VLC 2.0.3.

I also have a 10.8 machine with VLC 2.0.6, and was hoping for a method that wouldn't get blown away every time I upgrade VLC. On that machine I've tried to use Platypus, but it fails to have any effect either (VLC opens up, but doesn't seem to open with the correct arguments).

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to create an applescript wrapper like:

```
do shell script "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --fullscreen"
```

for example.  Save the script as an application.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. VLC opens, no evidence that the argument was passed. I've looked, can't imagine that it's anything in the environment variables... yet it works correctly if ran manually from Terminal.app.

Comment: What command line arguments are you trying to set?  I just tested the applescript with `--language ja` (Japanese) and `--language de` (German), and in both cases, VLC started with the designated language.  Maybe make sure that VLC is not still running a previous instance before the script is started?

Comment: --rc-host=localhost:32009

Comment: You also need `-I rc` if you want to open up the remote control. So, `VLC -I rc --rc-host=localhost:32009`

Comment: And, having said that, something is definitely wonky when adding those arguments to the applescript.  My VLC doesn't even open...

Comment: Nevermind -- VLC window apparently doesn't open in that mode.  But, I verified that the applescript opened the port up, and I could telnet to it.  When I did `ps`, a lot of previous instances of VLC were still running (not gui; but, Unix processes).  After killing them all, one final test with the applescript, and all was well.  Not sure on how to make VLC display a local window in this mode; but, that is another topic...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regular shell script file with .command extention

```
$ vi vlc.command

#/bin/sh
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --fullscreen


$ chmod 755 vlc.command
```

It will then be double-clickable from Finder.